# Any AS3/Air Library for Zip files with password protection support

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, encryption, passwords, zip

Is there any AS3/Air library for Zip files with password protection support?

Previously I checked [FZip](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/), it was great but it didn't support encryption. Also [another library](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15)
that works good, but it doesn't support encryption too.

Comment: I just need extraction! not creating or modifying.

Comment: i'd love to hear about that too

Comment: gotta love it when people shut your question down and then years later i want to get an answer and the question has still not been answered here or anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

hmm.. in fact there isn't but how about a work around using php .. if you like that then dig in ..
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php

Comment: Thank you, but it need's `php`, my application run in desktop mode.